# how onsuccess method of kinvey client call can be synchronize

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, null-pointer, kinvey

I am developing an app using Kinvey as backend. The problem i am getting is that when i call a kinvey appData request then the control don't go into onsuccess method of kinvey call and return back to the calling method place.
Here is my main class where i am calling a function which has kinvey client call to fetch data.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_list);
    // kinvey login here//

     // here is the function that fetch my data from kinvey
     GetAllCategory();

    imageUrls=urls // this is the assignment that cause Null pointer Exception

    }
```

now here is my GetAllCategories function

```
        public void GetAllCategory(){
       AsyncAppData<EntityCategories> myEvents=mKinveyClient.appData("categories",  EntityCategories.class);                                      
       myEvents.get(new Query(), new KinveyListCallback<EntityCategories>(){
       @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to save event data", error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(EntityCategories[] result1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //  Log.e(TAG,"Name is "+result1[0].get("name"));
        //  Log.e(TAG,"type is"+result1[0].get("type"));

            categories=result1;
            //onPrintCategoryClick();
        for(int i=0;i<categories.length;i++){

            imageUrls[i]=(String) categories[i].get("icon");

        }

        }


    });
    }
```

but control goes back to oncreate method just after executing kinvey call and don't go to the onSuccess method. After executing whole oncreate method it come back to onSuccess. but till then app got crash due to NUll pointer exception.

pardon my bad formating, ask me if anything you want me to explain more. Anticipatory thanks

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but just in-case someone else comes looking:

As is clear from the name - AsyncAppData, the Kinvey call to get data is executed asynchronously.

The best thing to do would be to assign the urls in the onSuccess method. Until then you should show a progress dialog to let the user know what's happening.